# Quantmod getSymbols returns date and not time when import from CSV

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

When doing getSymbols from CSV i'm only getting dates, but no time. I have specified the date/time format, what am i doing wrong?

I'm running this command

```
 getSymbols(symbols, verbose=TRUE, src='csv', dir="~/trading/R/Data/",format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S", col.names=c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"))
```

and the format of my CSV is

```
20150302 130100,50.57,50.58,50.53,50.56,263
20150302 130200,50.57,50.64,50.56,50.62,219
```

if i look at the imported xts

```
           CL.Open CL.High CL.Low CL.Close CL.Volume
2015-03-02   50.57   50.64  50.56    50.62       219
```

No time?

Yet if i run this command on an existing dataframe (dtfrm)

```
as.xts(read.zoo(dtfrm, tz='', format='%Y%m%d %H%M%S'))
```

I get the time as expected.

Comment: This is [a known issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/52).

Comment: OK thanks, I've found another way to achieve my goal. As per answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a current known issue, the workaround i'm doing is reading the CSV as a table then converting it to XTS.